# How to remove Done and Cancel button on keyboard?

Tags: c#, iphone, unity-game-engine, keyboard

I use Unity to create iPhone game.

When I checked "Hide mobile input", the preview form was hidden.

However, the Done and Cancel button is not hidden.

**Question**

- How do I hide the "Done, Cancel" button that appears at the top of the keyboard?

Comment: [Tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"Avoid inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats: [tag]: [question title]"_ (etc.) _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

I used the [UnityMobileInput](https://github.com/mopsicus/UnityMobileInput) plugin .
You need to uncheck "show Done button" and "show clear button" on Inspector View.